# Is it possible to use TPUs from local kernel?

Tags: tpu

I'm trying to train a model with TPUs but do I have to use Google Colab or similar platforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only train models on TPUs using Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on your model. If it is medium-sized or big like AlexNet or VGG19, you have to use Google Colab or Kaggle or other similar platforms which offer you free, limited-time access to their TPUs. If your model is light like LeNet, you can train it on your own computer even if you have only a CPU (not GPU). When using Colab, don't forget to change the runtime into TPU.